# Trying to make img's sit absolutely positioned at the bottom of their parent div

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

From my understanding you can use absolute positioning inside of it's parent to place it exactly where ever you want. Like explained here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

I'm trying to get my img elements to sit on the bottom of their parent divs but when I give the img's an absolute position the layout breaks. It seems like I need to assign a height to the section or the divs but nothing seems to work.

Please note that I commented out the absolute positioning on the images in the css so the layout is more presentable

```
<head>

</head>

<body>

<section id="artImages">

<div id="artImage1">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/288/200" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="artImage2">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/144/160" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="artImage3">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/673/300" alt="" />
</div>

</section>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    margin: 100 auto;
}

section#artImages {
    width: 673px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

    section#artImages div {
        float: right;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

        div#artImage1 {
            width: 288px;
        }

        div#artImage2 {
            width: 144px;
        }

    section#artImages div img {
        width: 100%;
        /* position: absolute; */
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PsMff/ Below is an illustration of what I'm looking for.

[image: illustration of div's and images]

Comment: you've to assign images' parent elements some height as `position:absolute` _disconnects_ them from the layout and they don't affect their parents' height anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct ... the `div`s need to have some `hight` assigned, **if you want to keep the current html markup**.

**Note:** you also don't need to use the html elements' tag-names in combination with `id`s (e.g. `div#artImage1`), as one `id` can only refer to one specific element in the markup.

You could try something like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrZv4/)), I gave the `div`s `hight: 300px`:

```
section {display: block}
#artImages {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 673px;
}
#artImages div {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height:300px;
}
#artImage1 {
    width: 288px;
}
#artImage2 {
    width: 144px;
}
#artImage3 {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#artImages div img {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

### Another option:

If you **don't want to assign a height** to the divs, but rather have it adjust to the higher one of them,
wrap another container around the upper two `div`s. Here I added the `#floater` `div` to your markup:

```
<section id="artImages">
    <div id="floater">
        <div id="artImage2">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/144/160" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="artImage1">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/288/200" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="artImage3">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/673/300" alt="" />
    </div>
</section>
```

and now float right the `#floater` and use `display:inline-block;` on `#artImage1` and `#artImage2` and `bottom:0;` on images. Something like this:

```
section {display: block}
#artImages {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 673px;
}
#floater, #artImage3 {
    float:right;
}
#artImage1, #artImage2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 288px;
}
#artImage2 { width: 144px }
#artImage3 { width: 100% }
#artImages img {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VrZv4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` attribute in place of `id`, then add the following code

```
  position : relative;
  bottom : 0px;
  clear : both;
```